# JS Onclick function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Html:

```
<div class="prog shrink" id="prog">
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="svg/close.svg" class="collapse" id="collapse">
    <div class="progNum" style="--i: 'Program 1'">
      <div>
        <h1>1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <h1>Program 01:</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu ipsum in elit congue blandit. Nullam vitae lobortis lorem, sagittis convallis felis. Praesent tincidunt tristique. Nullam vitae lobortis lorem, sagittis convallis felis. </p>
    <div class="btns"> <button class="btn btn1 showDiv3"> <img src="svg/dash.svg"> </button> <button class="btn btn2"> <span>Source code</span> <img src="svg/arrow.svg"> </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <div class="h-div3">
      <h1>C++</h1>
      <img src="svg/close.svg" class="div3-close">
    </div>
    <div class="d-link-div3"> <span>Download</span> <a href="">Turbo C++ Code</a> <a href="">Dev C++ Code</a>
    </div>
    <div class="c-link-div3"> <span>Compiler</span> <a href="">Compile</a>
    </div>
    <div class="view-div3"> <span>View Code</span> <a href="">View Code</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When a user click on `div.prog shrink` the class name changes to `div.prog expand`

I want to add the class shrink and remove the class expand when a user click on `img.collapse#collapse`

I tried:

```
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('collapse');
var prog = document.getElementById('prog');
closeBtn.onclick = function(){
   console.log('close button clicked..');
   prog.classList.remove('expand');
   prog.classList.add('shrink');
}
```

The output statement is displaying on the console but the div is not returning to its initial state.

Full code :

```js
var progElements = document.getElementsByClassName('prog');
var closeBtn = document.getElementById('collapse');
for (let i = 0; i < progElements.length; i++) {
  progElements[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.add('expand');
    this.classList.remove('shrink');
    for (let j = 0; j < progElements.length; j++) {
      if (i !== j) {
        if (!progElements[j].classList.contains('shrink')) {
          progElements[j].classList.add('shrink');
          progElements[j].classList.remove('expand');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var showDiv3 = document.getElementsByClassName('showDiv3');
var div3 = document.getElementsByClassName('div3');
var div3Close = document.getElementsByClassName('div3-close');

for (let i = 0; i < div3.length; i++) {
  showDiv3[i].onclick = function() {
    div3[i].style.display = 'block';
    div3[i].style.zIndex = '100';
  }
  div3Close[i].onclick = function() {
    div3[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

var closeBtn = document.getElementById('collapse');
var prog = document.getElementById('prog');
closeBtn.onclick = function() {
  console.log('close button clicked..');
  prog.classList.remove('expand');
  prog.classList.add('shrink');
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400;700&family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400;600;700;900&display=swap");
* {
  outline: 0px solid #0f0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(60px);
  width: calc(100vw - 60px);
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #152644;
}

.container .title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  background: #11101d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .title h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background: var(--rainbow);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.container .content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 66px);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.home-content {
  border: 0px solid #fff;
}

.home-content h1 {
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px solid #aaa;
}

.home-content .hc-links {
  border: 0px solid #f0f;
}

.home-content .hc-links div {
  border: 0px solid #0ff;
}

.home-content .hc-links div h1 {
  border: 0px solid #faa;
}

.home-content .hc-links div a {
  border: 0px solid #ff0;
}

.home-content .fback {
  border: 0;
}

.content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.content .prog.shrink {
  margin: 16px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.05), inset 0 -5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.05), 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.content .prog.expand {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 20;
  box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.prog.shrink .div1 {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  background: #11101d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.prog.expand .div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.prog.shrink .div1 .collapse {
  display: none;
}

.prog.expand .div1 .collapse {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  filter: invert(1);
  background: #778;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.prog.shrink .div1 .progNum {
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background: rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.45);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.prog.shrink .div1 .progNum::after {
  content: var(--i);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -28px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #0088ff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.prog.expand .div1 .progNum {
  background: #0088ff;
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}

.prog.shrink .div1 .progNum>div {
  background: #11101d;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.prog.expand .div1 .progNum>div {
  background: #def;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.prog.shrink .div1 .progNum>div>h1 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #0088ff;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.prog.expand .div1 .progNum>div>h1 {
  font-size: 52px;
}

.prog.shrink div2 {
  display: none;
}

.prog.expand .div2 {
  padding: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

.prog.expand .div2 h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.prog.expand .div2 p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.prog.expand .div2 .btns {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #0bc42a;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn1 {
  padding: 10px;
}

.prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn2 span {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn img {
  filter: invert(1);
}

.prog.expand .div3 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #11101d;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .h-div3 {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  min-height: 50px;
  background: #007bff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .h-div3 h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .h-div3 img {
  filter: invert(1);
  height: 30px;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .d-link-div3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .d-link-div3 span {
  background: #11101d;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.3);
}

.prog.expand .div3 .d-link-div3 a {
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .c-link-div3 {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .c-link-div3 span {
  background: #11101d;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.3);
}

.prog.expand .div3 .c-link-div3 a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .view-div3 {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.prog.expand .div3 .view-div3 span {
  background: #11101d;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -11px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.3);
}

.prog.expand .div3 .view-div3 a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .home-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 10px 22px;
    min-width: 270px;
    min-height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #11101d;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.05), inset 0 -5px 5px rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.05), 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .home-content h1 {
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  }
  .home-content .hc-links {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  .home-content .hc-links div {
    padding: 12px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  .home-content .hc-links div:nth-child(2) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .home-content .hc-links div h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #def;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  .home-content .hc-links div a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #007bff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .container .content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .content .prog.shrink {
    margin: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
  .content .prog.expand {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 370px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    background: #11101d;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .prog.expand .div1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background: #007bff;
  }
  .prog.expand .div1 .collapse {
    height: 32px;
    filter: invert(0);
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
  }
  .prog.expand .div1 .progNum {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -37px;
    left: 15px;
    background: #11101d;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    padding: 7px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .prog.expand .div1 .progNum>div {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .prog.expand .div1 .progNum>div>h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 {
    padding: 8px 16px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 270px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 h1 {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 p {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 16.5px;
    color: rgba(250, 250, 255, 0.8);
    height: 160px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 .btns {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn1 {
    padding: 4px 5px;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn1 img {
    height: 28px;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn2 span {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .prog.expand .div2 .btns .btn2 img {
    height: 25px;
  }
  .prog.expand .div3 .d-link-div3 {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .prog.expand .div3 .d-link-div3 a {
    margin: 7px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>C++ programs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sideBar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="main">
    <!--< --sideBar-- >-->
    <section class="sidebar close" id="sideBar">

      <div class="logo-section close" id="logoSection">
        <img src="svg/cpp.svg" id="btn1">
        <h1>C++<span>programs</span></h1>
        <img src="svg/bar.svg" id="btn2" class="close">
      </div>

      <ul class="nav-list close" id="navList">
        <li>
          <a href="11th.html" class="navLinks">
            <img src="svg/1.svg" class="navImg">
            <span class="navItem">
                         11th class
                      </span>
          </a>
          <span class="tooltip">
                      11th class
                   </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="12th.html" class="navLinks">
            <img src="svg/2.svg" class="navImg">
            <span class="navItem">
                         12th class
                      </span>
          </a>
          <span class="tooltip">
                      12th class
                   </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="others.html" class="navLinks">
            <img src="svg/3.svg" class="navImg">
            <span class="navItem">
                         Others
                      </span>
          </a>
          <span class="tooltip">
                      Others
                   </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="feedback.html" class="navLinks">
            <img src="svg/4.svg" class="navImg">
            <span class="navItem">
                         Feedback
                      </span>
          </a>
          <span class="tooltip">
                      Feedback
                   </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="more.html" class="navLinks">
            <img src="svg/5.svg" class="navImg">
            <span class="navItem">
                         More
                      </span>
          </a>
          <span class="tooltip">
                      More
                   </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="FAQ.html" class="navLinks">
            <img src="svg/6.svg" class="navImg">
            <span class="navItem">
                         FAQ
                      </span>
          </a>
          <span class="tooltip">
                      FAQ
                   </span>
        </li>
        <li class="theme">
          <a id="theme">
            <span>
                         Darkmode
                      </span>
            <img src="svg/sun.svg" id="ThemeImg">
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>










    <!--< --content-section-- >-->
    <section class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>C++ programs</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="content 11th">

        <!--program 1-->
        <div class="prog shrink" id="prog">
          <div class="div1">
            <img src="svg/close.svg" class="collapse" id="collapse">
            <div class="progNum" style="--i: 'Program&nbsp;1'">
              <div>
                <h1>1</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="div2">
            <h1>Program 01:</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu ipsum in elit congue blandit. Nullam vitae lobortis lorem, sagittis convallis felis. Praesent tincidunt tristique. Nullam vitae lobortis lorem, sagittis convallis felis.
            </p>
            <div class="btns">
              <button class="btn btn1 showDiv3">
                                   <img src="svg/dash.svg">
                                </button>
              <button class="btn btn2">
                                   <span>Source code</span>
                                   <img src="svg/arrow.svg">
                                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="div3">
            <div class="h-div3">
              <h1>C++</h1>
              <img src="svg/close.svg" class="div3-close" />
            </div>
            <div class="d-link-div3">
              <span>Download</span>
              <a href="">Turbo C++ Code</a>
              <a href="">Dev C++ Code</a>
            </div>
            <div class="c-link-div3">
              <span>Compiler</span>
              <a href="">Compile</a>
            </div>
            <div class="view-div3">
              <span>View Code</span>
              <a href="">View Code</a>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--program 2-->
        <div class="prog shrink" id="prog">
          <div class="div1">
            <img src="svg/close.svg" class="collapse">
            <div class="progNum" style="--i: 'Program&nbsp;2'">
              <div>
                <h1>2</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="div2">
            <h1>Program 02:</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu ipsum in elit congue blandit. Nullam vitae lobortis lorem, sagittis convallis felis. Praesent tincidunt tristique. Nullam vitae lobortis lorem, sagittis convallis felis.
            </p>
            <div class="btns">
              <button class="btn btn1">
                        <img src="svg/dash.svg">
                     </button>
              <button class="btn btn2">
                        <span>Source code</span>
                        <img src="svg/arrow.svg">
                     </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>

    </section>

  </section>
  <script src="js/sidebar.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  <script>
    links[0].classList.add('active');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to close the div by changing its class from `prog expand` to  `prog shrink`

Can anyone tell how can I achieve that ...

`Full project :`  [link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vh3fm8otuzmxl8v/Content_2.zip/file)

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to have a unique id for example `id="prog-one"` `id="prog-two"`.
2. Secondly you need to set the data-target attribute so you can target specific div to toggle(add/remove) classes like this.
   `<img src="svg/close.svg" class="collapse" data-target="prog-two" id="collapse">`
3. Finally you have to get all the collapse image and add the event listener.

```js
var closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.collapse');
    closeBtns.forEach(closeBtn => {
      closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function({target}) {
        const targetId = target.getAttribute('data-target');
        const targetDOM = document.getElementById(targetId);
      console.log('close button clicked..');
      targetDOM.classList.remove('expand');
      targetDOM.classList.add('shrink');
    })
    })
```

Here is the code pen link. [LINK ONE](https://codepen.io/chhiring90/pen/zYPNqEN?editors=1111) [LINKTWO](https://codepen.io/chhiring90/pen/rNYjLvK?editors=0010)

[UPDATED]

```js
var progElements = document.getElementsByClassName("prog");
var closeBtn = document.getElementById("collapse");
for (let i = 0; i < progElements.length; i++) {
  progElements[i].onclick = function ({ target }) {
    if (target.getAttribute("class") === "collapse") return;
    this.classList.add("expand");
    this.classList.remove("shrink");
    console.log("running");
    for (let j = 0; j < progElements.length; j++) {
      if (i !== j) {
        if (!progElements[j].classList.contains("shrink")) {
          progElements[j].classList.add("shrink");
          progElements[j].classList.remove("expand");
        }
      }
    }
  };
}

var showDiv3 = document.getElementsByClassName("showDiv3");
var div3 = document.getElementsByClassName("div3");
var div3Close = document.getElementsByClassName("div3-close");

for (let i = 0; i < div3.length; i++) {
  showDiv3[i].onclick = function () {
    div3[i].style.display = "block";
    div3[i].style.zIndex = "100";
  };
  div3Close[i].onclick = function () {
    div3[i].style.display = "none";
  };
}

var closeBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".collapse");
closeBtns.forEach((closeBtn) => {
  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function ({ target }) {
    const targetId = target.getAttribute("data-target");
    const targetDOM = document.getElementById(targetId);
    console.log("close button clicked..");
    targetDOM.className = "prog shrink";
  });
});
```

Comment: It's also not working

Comment: Here is my whole project   [link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/vh3fm8otuzmxl8v/Content_2.zip/file)

Comment: While clicking the `<img class="collapse"/>` it was also triggering event on the parent div `<div class="prog">...</div>`. In order to prevent it I've added the condition `if (target.getAttribute("class") === "collapse") return;`. Please check the [UPDATED] Snippet. Thank you. And you can check the article about more info here.
(Link)[https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing]